# Reading a "library-local" text file when library is imported by another file (importlib.resources)

Tags: python-3.7, python-importlib

I have a library that has a structure like this:

```
- gps
  - static
    - __init__.py
    - datafile.dat
  - __init__.py
  - gps.py
```

In `gps.py`, there is code like this:

```
from importlib import resources
from . import static

def get_data():
  f = resources.open_text(static, 'datafile.dat')
  return f
```

This code is part of a library, which is imported into another project; we'll call the library `gps`.

Then, in the client code, we have code like this:

```
import gps

....

file = gps.get_data()
```

I have tests for the library to check `get_data()` that work fine.  But when I try to use this in the client code, it gives me a FileNotFoundError, with a stack trace that looks like this:

```
  ....
  File "/home/glewis/miniconda3/envs/client_code/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gps-py3.7.egg/gps/gps.py", line 63, in get_data
    f = resources.open_text(static, 'datafile.dat')
  File "/home/glewis/miniconda3/envs/client_code/lib/python3.7/importlib/resources.py", line 125, in open_text
    return TextIOWrapper(reader.open_resource(resource), encoding, errors)
  File "/home/glewis/miniconda3/envs/client_code/lib/python3.7/importlib/resources.py", line 285, in open_resource
    raise FileNotFoundError(path)
FileNotFoundError: gps/static/datafile.dat
```

I thought I was using importlib properly, but it looks like I'm obviously missing some key part of it.  Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Basically, I want to have `datafile.dat` stored in the `gps` library, but have the client libraries be agnostic to the datafile itself - they should just call `get_data()` and not worry about where it's stored.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, it was an issue with my `setup.py` file used as part of the package build; I needed to make sure that I had something like this in the setup:

```
...
package_data={"gps": ["static/*.dat"]}
...
```